# Uncaught error: require is undefined in node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, requirejs

I am new to JavaScript and jQuery. I am doing my project using Node.js.

When I run my server my webpage is running. And I want to push the data entered by the user to mongodb. So I have included `require("Mongodb")` in my javascript file.

But when I get into this event, in the console log I'm getting the error as require is undefined.

I have enabled JavaScript in my browser. But the same error is repeating. So I am following requirejs.

There are a lot of procedures to be followed as per a link provided in some website. Since I am new to JavaScript I am not able to follow it. Can anyone help me to overcome this?

I have four files as src files for my webpage.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do you get the error message? In the browser or on the server?

Comment: It sounds like you are confused whether it's a browser or node environment problem, but without more details it's hard to say. Especially I doubt this has anything to do with mongodb.

Comment: can you give some source?

Comment: The error is coming in the browser.

Comment: I included the source file of the requirejs in my html with the help of script tag as "** <script src="requirejs/require.js"></script>  ** ". And the error in the console log is "** require.js:1 Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function (t){function e(e,i){var ....**" followed by rest of the script in require.js file.

Comment: @modernator yes. i'm really confused!

Comment: @t.niese I get the errors in the browser's console log.

Comment: @modernator i followed the youtube source "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eRqsZqLyYaU" and I was not able to follow. So I didnt follow from that moment.